# C# Skype4Com send HTML message

Tags: c#, html, tags, sendmessage, skype4com

I've delayed asking this question as long as I can, but I still cannot find an answer anywhere (Or even a question!). As most Skype users likely know, there was a version (5.7 I believe) that could send over basic HTML in messages when holding Ctrl + Shift while pressing the send button. My question is if it is possible to send that same basic HTML through Skype4Com. I send messages using

`ichat.SendMessage(string Message);`

which clearly would not convert the HTML tags. I've tried a variety of things such as holding Ctrl + Shift while the message sends, I've tried doing

`skype.Client.ButtonPressed(string Key);`

which according to the only documentation I could find on that function (Python) does not contain anything for Shift or Ctrl. (I tried both anyway, but it hangs there because the keys don't exist.) I noticed inside skype.Client that there was a

`skype.Client.OpenMessageDialog(string Name, string Message)`

which would do perfectly fine for me (It opens the chat window for username "name" and types out the message but does not send it (I could then just simulate key events for Ctrl and Shift and then set a point for the mouse to click or something)), however it does not work for groups. So I'm wondering if there's anyone who knows if it's possible to either send HTML directly or type out to a group without sending the message via Skype4Com?